# Visual Studio constantly including protractor typings from npm module folder in the project file

Tags: visual-studio, npm, protractor

My team and I are having a strange problem where although our node_modules folder is excluded from the project, the npm_modules\protractor\Typings folder keeps reincluding itself.

This wouldn't be a problem, we could live with it being there, but it not only does it include itself once, but every subsequent time it does it, it adds duplicate includes to the project file.

Is there anyway to absolutely force it to not include anything from that folder, or has anyone had a similar issue to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else finding this post, the issue is caused by NodeJS Tools for Visual Studio, and a bug with their Automatic Typings Acquisition.

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Automatic-Typings-Acquisition

Issue is logged on GitHub here and has been fixed in Alpha 2.

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/921